# How do I get a series of documents from Firestore and return them all in an array?

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

My Firestore data has the following structure:

`topics` collection containing documents with the following structure:

```
id: string
name: string
tag: string
infoID: string
```

these map to an `ITopic` interface:

```
interface ITopic {
    id: string
    name: string
    tag: string
    infoID: string
}
```

`infos` collection containing documents with the following structure:

```
id: string
content: string
topicID: string or null
```

which map to:

```
interface IInfo {
    id: string
    content: string
    topicID: string | null
}
```

So each `topic` document has an associated `info` document, and vice-versa (ie a one-to-one mapping).

I've retrieved all my `topic` documents from the database and now I want to get the associated info for each one, all in an array.  So each item in the array would be an object with `topic` and `info` fields:

```
  interface ITopicInfo {
    topic: ITopic
    info: IInfo
  }
```

I've tried this (`topics` is the existing array of all my topics):

```
async function getTopicsInfo(db: Firestore, topics:Array<ITopic>) {
  try {
    let topicsInfo:Array<ITopicInfo> = topics.map((topic) => {
      const infoRef = doc(db, 'infos', topic.infoID);
      const infoSnap = await getDoc(infoRef);
      if (infoSnap.exists()) {
        const result = infoSnap.data();
        const newTopicInfo:ITopicInfo = {
            topic: topic,
            info: {
              id: result.id
              content: result.content
              topicID: result.topicID
            },
        };
        return newTopicInfo;
      } else return null;
    });
    return topicsInfo;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting a TypeScript error saying

`Type '(Promise<ITopicTree | null> | null)[]' is not assignable to type '(ITopicTree | null)[]'.`

- it looks like it's returning the Promise rather than the result, basically.  How do I fix this?

Comment: did you try changing `await getDoc(infoRef)` into `getDoc(infoRef).then((res)=>{...})` and doing all your logic inside `then`?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to return map directly :
instead of doing this :

```
let topicsInfo:Array<ITopicInfo> = topics.map((topic) => { ...
```

Just do this :

```
return topics.map((topic) => { ...
```

UPDATE :

```
async function getTopicsInfo(db: Firestore, topics:Array<ITopic>): ITopicInfo[] { ...
```